# Merging 2d numpy arrays of different shapes to 3d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I currently have 3 different pandas 2d dataframes which I plan to convert to numpy arrays.

```
print(df1.shape)
print(df2.shape)
print(df3.shape)
```

Returns

```
(70000, 23)
(8, 2)
(70000, 8)
```

My plans are to get a 3D Array with shape:

```
(70000, 8, 26)
```

Where every value of df1 is the same in the missing dimension.
Same should account for df2.
(edit since there is some uncertainty)
df1 contains features that change over time but stay the same for every object.
df2 is constant over time, but has different values for different objects.
df3 contains the target value for every object at every timestep.

The expanded arrays should have the shapes:

```
(70000, 8, 23)
(70000, 8, 2)
(70000, 8, 1)
```

Just looping 70000 times to concatenate the array with itself does not seem reasonable to me.
I am aware that in the second step the arrays can just get merged.

Comment: Can you elaborate how each of these is being combined? its not very clear, How is this changing from 23 to 26 in the last axis?

Comment: I eddited my question in order to make it a little more clear hopefully.

Comment: This is still very unclear, "every value of `df1` is the same in the missing dimension" are you referring to `df1` with shape `70000, 23`? Which axis are you referring to here? Best way is you give us a small example which shows the transformation from `df1`, `df2`, `df3` to the 3D array with one or two components instead of 70,000.

Comment: How would you merge just one of those 7000  'rows'?  Better yet come up with a much smaller example.  Any answer will have to demonstrate that it does what you want.

Comment: Sorry for the bad problem discription. I added some more explaination. Thank you guys for your effords.

Comment: numpy has repeat and tile functions that can expand your arrays shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `broadcast_to` with `concatenate`. Here are the following steps -

```
#Step1
a = np.random.random((7000,23))
b = np.random.random((8,2))
c = np.random.random((7000,8))

#Step2
a1 = a[:,None,:]
b1 = b[None,:,:]
c1 = c[:,:,None]

#Step3
a2 = np.broadcast_to(a1,(a1.shape[0],b1.shape[1],a1.shape[2]))
b2 = np.broadcast_to(b1,(a1.shape[0],b1.shape[1],b1.shape[2]))
c2 = c1

#Final output
out = np.concatenate([a2,b2,c2], axis=-1)

#### Shape for the tensors ####
print('step 1 ->',a.shape, b.shape, c.shape)
print('step 2 ->',a1.shape, b1.shape, c1.shape)
print('step 3 ->',a2.shape, b2.shape, c2.shape)
print('final ->',out.shape)
```

```
step 1 -> (7000, 23) (8, 2) (7000, 8)
step 2 -> (7000, 1, 23) (1, 8, 2) (7000, 8, 1)
step 3 -> (7000, 8, 23) (7000, 8, 2) (7000, 8, 1)
final -> (7000, 8, 26)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @hpaulj here is my solution:

```
max_dim_0 = df3.shape[0]
max_dim_1 = df3.shape[1]
df1 = np.repeat(np.expand_dims(df1, axis=1), max_dim_1, axis=1)
df2 = np.repeat(np.expand_dims(df2, axis=0), max_dim_0, axis=0)
df3 = np.expand_dims(df3, axis=2)
concatenated_array = np.concatenate((df1, df2, df3), axis=2)
```

final shape:

```
print(concatenated_array.shape)
(70000, 8, 26)
```

Comment: `np.repeat()` involves copy of the internal data of the array. Since `np.concatenate()` also involves data-copy, you probably are doing more data-copy than is really necessary. Pls see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If `df1_arr`, `df2_arr`, and `df3_arr` are your 3 `numpy` arrays, you could create broadcasted views of the 3 arrays, and then concatenate those broadcasted views:

```
bv_df1_arr = np.broadcast_to (df1_arr[:, None, :], shape=(SEVENTY_THOUSAND, EIGHT, TWENTY_THREE))
bv_df2_arr = np.broadcast_to (df2_arr, shape=(SEVENTY_THOUSAND, EIGHT, TWO))
bv_df3_arr = np.broadcast_to (df3_arr[...,None], shape=(SEVENTY_THOUSAND, EIGHT, ONE))
result = np.concatenate((bv_df1_arr, bv_df2_arr, bv_df3_arr), axis=-1)
```